# How to select value from a JSON which contains a string array?

Tags: c#, json

I was trying to select a particular value from JSON data, one of its data is a string array(string[]) and after selecting this value I want to assign this value to a **string[]** type variable.
What I already tried is passing it key-value and as a result, I will get its value.

This is the function I have written to get the data from JSON

```
private object[] getValueFromJSONForObject(string property, string json)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic routes_list = (dynamic)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
    return routes_list[property];
}
```

and I'm accessing the function here

```
PFFilter = new string[] 
{ 
    getValueFromJSONForObject("PFFilter", savedReportsVM.BaseFilter).ToString() 
}
```

but I didn't get the expected result.

Here is the JSON data

```
{
  "DateAsOnFormated": "02-Mar-2020",
  "LookaheadDays": "90",
  "PFFilter": [
    "P",
    "F"
  ],
  "OverDueGreaterThan": "",
  "OverDueLessThan": ""
}
```

I'm expecting a result like this

```
{string[2]}
```

and inside this [0] "P" [1] "F"

now what I get is `{string[1]}` and nothing is inside the string array, How can I fix this code

Comment: `getValueFromJSONForObject("PFFilter", savedReportsVM.BaseFilter).ToString()` just returns a single string.  Why are you expecting two?

Comment: But here I didn't get even the single value. How can I modify the code to get proper result.

Comment: Are you doing this on a web server?  Normally I'd use [JSON.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this.  Interestingly, the first sentence of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) says precisely this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm doing this in the controller, and it works fine with other data, the return type was **String** and I modify this with **object[]**  when I get an error with that function return type

Comment: Are you sure your json string is as you have it, because your code works as is for me.

Comment: Just remove the `ToString()` and you should get what you want.  `getValueFromJSONForObject("PFFilter", savedReportsVM.BaseFilter);` returns an `object[2]` containing "P" and "F".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok let me try with this

Comment: @RobertHarvey It shows an error , **Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'string' **

Comment: Yes, I would have expected that.  It's an array of `Object[]`.  Just convert each element to a string in the usual way (by calling `ToString()` when you retrieve the element).  See Sajid's technique below, if you really want a `String[]` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete `ToString()` in

```
PFFilter = new string[] 
{ 
    getValueFromJSONForObject("PFFilter", savedReportsVM.BaseFilter).ToString() 
}
```

and replace it by the following code :

```
objetc[] result = getValueFromJSONForObject("PFFilter", savedReportsVM.BaseFilter);
// convert each object to string
string[] PFFilter = Array.ConvertAll(result, x => x.ToString());
```

i hope that will help you fix the issue

Comment: Ok let me try with this one